# How do I display content with the Views module when more than one language is enabled?

Tags: drupal-7

How do I display content with the Views module when more than one language is enabled?

I have a site running Drupal 7.17, with two enabled languages (English and Japanese). I created view showing nodes, and used the Internationalization module to translate.

[image: English]

[image: Japanese]

When English is set as language, everything is OK; when the language is Japanese, I don't know how to display Japanese content.

I added the following code into the block which was created by the Views module.

```
<?php
  global $language;
  $lang_name = $language->language;
  if ($lang_name == "ja") {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
?>
```

With English, it displays "Page not found."

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new "FILTER CRITERIA"- Content: Language (= Current user's language) in views